# Vmware MacOS-BigSur in win10

Tags: macos-big-sur, vmware-workstation, amd-processor

I'm used Vmware Workstation 15.5 PRO to build MacOS Big Sur in Win10 and I refer this website.

https://www.wikigain.com/install-macos-big-sur-on-vmware-windows-pc/

My device:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600x
- Display card: NVIDIA 1070ti
- RAM: 16GB
- Operating System: Windows 10 1909x64

I did the sixth step but an error occurred.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbiYb.png)

> The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.

I tried the commands from other website.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogEPiiufrO0&ab_channel=CAPSTV

And used the command.

`smc.version = "0"`
`cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"`
`cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"`
`cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"`
`cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"`
`cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"`
`cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"`
`cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"`
`cpuid.1.edx = "0000:1111:1010:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"`
`featureCompat.enable = "FALSE"`

But there are still errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID34D.png)

> Feature 'cpuid.intel' was absent, but must be present.

> Module 'FeatureCompatLate' power on failed.

> Failed to start the virtual machine.

I have read many websites saying that MacOS does not support non-MacOS CPUs.
What should I do if I am using AMD's device?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 29):

### AMD Ryzen 7 5800X VMWare macOS settings

Not sure, but it can help other 5xxx series AMD Ryzen CPUs as well for macos vm running issues

common issues:

1. The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system.
   Power off or reset the virtual machine.
2. Feature 'cpuid.ds' was absent, but must be present.
   Feature 'cpuid.ss' was absent, but must be present.
   Module 'FeatureCompatLate' power on failed.
3. Failed to start the virtual machine.

### FIX: paste the below to the vmx file end

(my working settings on AMD Ryzen 5800X tested ok)

```
smc.version = "0"
cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"
cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"
cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"
cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"
cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"
cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "iMac19,1"
board-id = "Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95"
```

### The basic settings come from many source like this:

Install:
https://www.geekrar.com/install-macos-catalina-on-vmware-on-windows-pc/

CPU has been disabled Issue:
https://www.geekrar.com/how-to-fix-the-cpu-has-been-disabled-by-the-guest-os/#comment-21413

### Differences fixing the macos VM on my Ryzen 7 5800X:

featureCompat.enable completly removed, if it FALSE then VM failed to start, if it TRUE causing Module 'FeatureCompatLate' power on failed. message

I have to change two 1 to 0 than other posts on the cpuid.1.edx
It solved the cpuid.ss and cpuid.ds message

from:
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:**1**111:10**1**0:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"

to:
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:**0**111:10**0**0:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"

### VM hardware version setting tested ok:

15.X
16.X

VM hardware can be configured without any problem on VM guest:
CPU core: 2, 4, 8 or 16
RAM: 4, 8 or 16 GB
Hard Disk: SATA or nvme
Display: any resolution (VMware tools have to be installed to use)

### VM host software config tested ok:

VMWARE Workstation PRO 16.2.1
unlocker 3.0.2 or unlocker 3.0.3

### Geekrar.com macos versions tested ok:

macOS Catalina Final by Geekrar.rar
macOS Mojave Final APFS by Geekrar.rar

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps:

Go to VM -> Manage -> Change Hardware Compatibility and select Workstation 10.x

```
smc.version = "0"
cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"
cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"
cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"
cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"
cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"
cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "iMac19,1"
board-id = "Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95"
```

It worked for me on VMware Workstation 16.2.3 build-19376536 and AMD Ryzen 9 5950X.

Answer (score 3):

**VMware 17**

I would get an error that said that the VMX file is corrupt. Removing the SMC.Version = "0" resovled this for me and the VM still works great.

```
cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"
cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"
cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"
cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"
cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"
cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "iMac19,1"
board-id = "Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95"
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to `VM -> Manage -> Change Hardware Compatibility` and select `Workstation 10.x`
2. Replace `cpuid.1.edx = "0000:1111:1010:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"` with `cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"`
3. Remove `featureCompat.enable = "FALSE"`

It worked for me on VMware Workstation 15.5.6 and AMD Ryzen 5 2600.

Answer (score 1):

These are the configs that I used for VMWare Workstation 16 player to install MacOS 11 Big Sur.

PC Specs.

- Ryzen 7 5800H
- 32 GB
- RTX 3070

.vmx file configs

```
virtualHW.version = "10"
smc.version = "0"
cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"
cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"
cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"
cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"
cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"
cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "iMac19,1"
board-id = "Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95"
```

FYI: Keep the USB Controller as 2.0; otherwise, your keyboard and mouse might not work.

Comment: question: regarding your config, or any working mac on vmware on windows, did you have to disable Hyper-V? I use WSL2 too much to do that.